# Input from Tablet/Phone on Pc

Tags: android

A new project I've been thinking about, done programming before but new to android development in general.
I aim to make an app for a phone and then for a tablet that can interact with my pc, showing it's open apps or moving windows around. (Done wirelessly or with Bluetooth I don't care)

How can I make that a thing? I've found nothing on the internet. Thank You!

Comment: Install a VNC viewer?

Comment: From what I understood it doesn't seem like the thing I need, I want to be able to move windows from screen to screen (I have 3 screens) with a swipe on my tablet, I want to click a chrome icon on the tablet and make it open on the pc, is really VNC the thing I'm looking for ? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: VNC is a protocol to view (and control) the screen of a remote machine, so when you open a chrome icon in the tablet, it will open in the PC (although you will be able to view it open from the tablet, too). I'm not sure how it would handle multiple PC screens (it may even depend on the specific VNC software you use on the table and on the PC).

Comment: so it seems like the perfect thing! Thank you for your help <3

Comment: Ok, I have posted the above as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a VNC client on the Tablet/Phone.

[VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) is a protocol to view (and control) the screen of a remote machine, so when you open a chrome icon in the tablet, it will open in the PC (although you will be able to view it open from the tablet, too).